# socket.io emit only to sender outside the socket.on('connect')

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, emit

Is it possible to global emit only to sender but outside the socket.on('connect') event? I'm looking for something like `socket.broadcast.to().emit()` which I can use in app.post method, which is not in connect method, so I can't use just socket.emit

```
app.post('/room', function(req, res) {   
            io.sockets.emit('something');         

});
```

'something' I want to emit only to SENDER

My code:

```
socket_id;

app.post('/room', function(req, res) {
      if (req.body.user == ''){
         io.sockets.socket(socket_id).emit('usernameError', 'Type your username');
    }
    else if (users[req.body.user] !== undefined ) {
      io.sockets.socket(socket_id).emit('usernameError', 'Username exists.'); 
    }  
            else{
        users[req.body.user] = req.body.user;
        user = req.body.user;
        io.sockets.emit('newUser', user+' join to the room');             
               res.render('room');
                  }     
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) { 
   socket.username = user;
   socket.join('room1');
   socket.id = socket_id;   
});
```

Comment: Do you send request to `/room` with AJAX or with HTML form?

Comment: I'm using Jade template: form(name="input", action='/room', method='post')

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you want to send "something" to the user that just came to `/room` page, right?
If so, you can't do it in `app.post` method because this code will execute **before** the client will receive the HTML code,
and thus handshake between client and server will not be established.

I think the best solution would be executing the following code on the client side on `/room` page only:

```
var socket = io.connect('/');   //your socket.io connection (may be different)
socket.on('something', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
socket.emit('i_am_room_page');  //tell server we are on /room page
```

And on the server:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('i_am_room_page', function(data) {
    socket.emit('something', {your: 'data'});
  });
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I updated my code. Your idea is good but I want do all this in app.post because I have a small validation there as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

If somehow you can store the socektID of the sender in a variable, then you can emit to that particular client in app.post method. Do something like this:

```
var id;
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('some event'){
    id = socket.id;
  }
});
```

and do this in app.post method:

```
app.post('/room', function(req, res) {
  io.sockets.socket(socketid).emit('event name', {data: yourData});
});
```

Though I've proposed this solution but your approach doesn't seem too convincing.

Comment: It sounds good but socketID is generated when client is connected so firstly app.post will be done. Look please at my update code. Maybe app.post can be inside io.sockets.on('connection') or after it? Is it right approach ?

Comment: are you rendering two pages to client? I mean first client hits a specific URL and you render, let's suppose, login.jade and after verification you render room.jade?

Comment: yes, index is a start page. app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
}); there is my login form

Comment: Then don't use socket in index page, Use AJAX to request and JSON to send login verification response like res.json(500, {error: 'err.....'}); and if user is verified, render him the room page and use socket in that page. If you don't understand this then let me know then i'll give you answer with code

Comment: I'm a little confused, will be grateful for your answer with code